# Initilize random 4D array

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm new around here and also very new to C++ language.
I'm currently making a C++ program which includes SFML for my school assignment.
Which is, a 9x9 TicTacToe with several twist.

Just want to know how can I randomize on each start a fixed number of mines around the 9x9 grid so that when a player clicks on it, they lose.
Im using 4D array like this array[R][C][r][c].

Thanks in advance!
Sorry if my question is hard to understand.

Comment: Read [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random) and google for examples, it might look daunting at first glance but it's not that hard.

Comment: Why do you need a 4d array? does a 2d array is not sufficient?

Comment: @user657267 thank you, i will read it now =)

Comment: @cell ah, thats because i need to create 9 3x3 grids in the big 9x9 grid =D

Comment: @xGraysen Ok, I haven't of course read your question completely ;)

Answer (score 0):

xGraysen,

I don't want to give away the answer to you, but this is how you would initialize a 2-D array with random values:

```
int main()
{
  int a, b;


   cout << ("how many rows are there? : ) " << endl; 
   cin >> a;


    cout << ("how many columns are there?: ) " << endl;
    cin >> b;

    int grade[a][b];

    srand (clock());

    for (int index1 = 0; index1 < a; index1++)
    {
         for (int index2 = 0; index2 < c; index2++) 
         {
            grade[index1][index2] = rand() % a*b; 
         }
    }
 }
```

Now try to abstract this for a 3-dimensional array and then a 4 dimensional array, and please let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Thanks for replying!
It's ok, this is just what I needed to know the basics at least.
I'll be sure to try it out!

what are the difference between srand(clock()) and srand(time())?

Comment: That's a really good question! The srand function takes a `seed` value which it basis it's random number generator off-of. So you can actually give it any value you would like, however there are input field's which will make your random function more non-deterministic (ie, more random!). The time() measures the real time while the clock() measures the processing time taken by the current process. If your process sleeps for any appreciable amount of time, or the system is busy with other processes, the two will be very different. But both are fine for your random number generator!

Comment: I see! That sounded really confusing for a newbie like me though.
Thanks again! I'll try to work something out =D

Comment: Glad to hear! &  Best of luck!! :D